# Higher order macros

Tags: rust

Is it possible in rust to write a macro that creates other macros. For example, suppose I define the following two macros:

```
macro_rules! myprint(
    ($a:expr) => (print!("{}", $a))
)

macro_rules! myprintln(
    ($a:expr) => (println!("{}", $a))
)
```

Since the two macros repeat a lot of code, I may want to write a macro to generate the macros.

I've tried to generate such a [meta macro](http://is.gd/TbiIPO).

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! metamacro(
    ($i:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $i (
            ($a:expr) => ({println!("hello {}", $a)})
        )
    );
)

metamacro!(foo)

fn main() {
    foo!(1i);
}
```

but get the following errors:

```
<anon>:6:13: 6:14 error: unknown macro variable `a`
<anon>:6             ($a:expr) => ({println!("hello {}", $a)})
                     ^
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
Program ended.
```

**Edit:** After playing around with the macros some more, I discovered that a higher order macro works as expected if the returned macro doesn't receive any arguments. For example, the following [code](http://is.gd/hLRO25)

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! metamacro(
    ($i:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $i (
            () => ({println!("hello")})
        )
    );
)

metamacro!(foo)

fn main() {
    foo!();
}
```

prints `hello`

Comment: Why not just to try yourself?

Comment: I have tried and failed to find something that works. I asked here in case there was a hidden or lesser known mechanism in rust that I hadn't tried yet. I'll add this to my question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: You haven’t shown what you tried or what the errors are. These details are absolutely necessary to be able to give any sort of answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was recently made possible in [#34925](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/34925). The answer below refers to older versions of Rust.

---

This is [#6795](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6795) and [#6994](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6994), and isn't directly possible at the moment. E.g. the first thing one would try is

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! define {
    ($name: ident, $other: ident) => {
        macro_rules! $name {
            ($e: expr) => {
                $other!("{}", $e)
            }
        }
    }
}

define!{myprintln, println}
define!{myprint, print}

fn main() {}
```

But this fails with

```
so8.rs:6:13: 6:14 error: unknown macro variable `e`
so8.rs:6             ($e: expr) => {
                     ^
```

(Filed [#15640](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15640) about the caret pointing at the `(` instead of the `$e`.)

The reason is macro expansion is "dumb": it naively interprets and replaces all the tokens, even inside nested macro invocations (and `macro_rules!` is a macro invocation). Hence, it can't tell that the `$e` inside the interior `macro_rules!` are actually meant to be left as `$e`: it's just trying to replace them when expanding `define`.

The second thing one might try is passing in extra arguments to `define` to place in the interior definition, so that the `$e` doesn't appear directly in the nested invocation:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! define {
    ($name: ident, $other: ident, $($interior: tt)*) => {
        macro_rules! $name {
            ($($interior)*: expr) => {
                $other!("{}", $($interior)*)
            }
        }
    }
}

define!{myprintln, println, $e}
define!{myprint, print, $e}

fn main() {}
```

That is, I added the `$interior: tt` to allow capturing the `$e`. `tt` stands for token tree, which is a non-delimiter raw token (e.g. `$` or `some_ident`) or a sequence of tokens surrounded by matching delimiters (e.g. `(foo + bar fn "baz")`). Unfortunately, it seems expansion is eager enough for the `$e` expansion to be expanded too:

```
so8.rs:8:13: 8:14 error: unknown macro variable `e`
so8.rs:8             ($($interior)*: expr) => {
                     ^
```

It works fine when the nested macro has no argument itself, because there is no nested `$...` non-terminals and so the expansion phase doesn't ever hit the definition problem described above.

---

Lastly, you can get some semblance of code sharing since you can expand to macro invocations by name:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! my {
    ($name: ident, $e: expr) => {
        $name!("{}", $e)
    }
}

fn main() {
    my!(print, 1i);
    my!(println, 2i);
}
```

which prints `12`.

Comment: Well, I'd say, perhaps we either make it work well, or don't allow nested macros all together...

Comment: Wow, terrific answer! Would you happen to know if higher order macros are planned for inclusion in the language some time in the future?

Comment: @mwhittaker, there's no current plan for this right now, but it is certainly an annoyance that would be nice to fix.

Comment: @mwhittaker (And, there's a few bugs covering it; I added links to them to the start of my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example that works, perhaps a starting point for you:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! metamacro(
    ($i:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $i (
            () => ({println!("hello!")})
        )
    );
)

metamacro!(hello)

fn main() {
    hello!();
}
```

Comment: error: macros that expand to items must be delimited with braces or followed by a semicolon


https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54ebf83a9c5247d2ab64e4dbbb407407

Answer (score 1):

there is a kind of ugly way:

```
macro_rules! metamacro {
    ($sign: tt $i: ident) => {
        macro_rules! $i {
            ($sign a: expr) => { println!("hello {}", $sign a) };
        }
    };
}

metamacro!{ $foo }

fn main() {
    foo!("1i");
}
```

I don't really know how this works but this code snippet compiles and runs on 2018.
Though this can get kind of ugly when there's a lot of syntax inside the arms of the macro.
This's just a workaround for the actual problem